# how to create a 100 checkboxes in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want to create 100 checkboxes, using javascript

I dont want to type one by one the checkboxes. I want javascript to do it for me, with a loop(like for or while)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add HTML control(s) via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275514/add-html-controls-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    var check = document.createElement("input");
    check.type = "checkbox";
    check.id = i;
    document.body.appendChild(check);
}
```

now you have 100 checkboxes in your body with ids starting from 0 to 99.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the below

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```